How should I review a non-reviewed Staging Ground question where I have nothing to add to the existing comment suggesting improvements?
On more than one occasion, I've encountered a Staging Ground question where others have already left useful comments and I have nothing more to add, but the question still needs Major Changes.
My preference would be that upvoting an existing comment would unlock the ability to vote for Major Changes. Since that's not possible, is the proper action to skip the question, or to add a new comment that re-iterates the same suggestions that have already been made so I can then vote for Major Changes?
Here is an example, where a user has left a comment with suggestions for improvement, but from what I can tell, there hasn't yet been a Major Changes vote.

If it's open for reevaluation... surely a new comment stating the changes didn't solve the previously noted problems and why, if applicable, would be helpful

Related: It should be possible to require major changes based on someone else's comment


is the proper action to skip the question, or to add a new comment that re-iterates the same suggestions that have already been made so I can then vote for Major Changes?

I prefer the latter. Leaving the question in a state other than Requires Major Changes allows it to, after 24 hours, be auto-graduated, and you clearly agree that it has problems that should prevent it from being posted on the main site. Since the system doesn't let us piggyback off of other users' feedback, we have to create our own in order to change the question's status.
I personally either reiterate the feedback any other users have made in my own words, or reuse the same comment template they used (or a better one), and hit Requires Major changes. Then, I'll go back and paste in a comment reply to the users who did not submit the question as requiring Major changes that they ideally should have. Here's the comment I use:

Next time, choose the "Require Major changes" review option on the right after posting your comment, and hit Submit. See also: What is Staging Ground?

Here's an example SG review where I did this. Screenshot, in case it's deleted:


I have also adopted this practice.

When some Reviewer would use any 'Magic Link', like [edit] / [mre] / [ask] / etc, in a Comment, the System / SG-Workflow should automatically propose a choice between the few Reviews available, the 'Requires Major Changes' being the first/obvious option... (+ an option to just post a "free" Comment, without casting some "official" Review).
